Options on Futures: Estimating implied volatility
In a commodities futures market, where there are options for the terminal expiry, whose implied volatility can be determined, I am interested in understanding what the implied volatility for an early-expiry option would be. To explain this better it might be easier:

I have the Z american option on the Z contract
I have the U american option on the U contract

for which I can estimate both their implied and historical volatilities.
However, what would be the implied volatility for an american option based on the Z contract but expiring at the same time as the U contract?
Thank you!

What do you mean by Z or U American options?

Z= December, U = September (commodity codes). See https://www.cmegroup.com/month-codes.html

Let's use the notation IV(option expiration date; futures expiration date) to refer to the implied volatility for an option expiring at "option expiration date" with underlying equal to the contract expiring at "futures expiration date". U refers to a known date in September and Z is a known date in December.
I would argue that IV(Z, Z), IV(U, U) and IV(U, Z) are three independent numbers and that neither can be computed from the other two (unless you make drastic simplifying assumptions).
IV(Z, Z) and IV(U, Z) reference the same contract but are unlikely to be the same unless you assume a flat time structure of volatility.
IV(U, U) and IV(U, Z) reference the same option expiration date, but refer to two different contracts, which are unlikely to have the same volatility. Generally (but not always) longer term futures respond less to current information and are therefore less volatile than nearer to expiration futures (this is sometimes called the Samuelson hypothesis (or Samuleson effect) of futures markets).
So I think the problem you pose has no solution ;)

Yes I agree with them being independent, but of course there must be some information linking them together due to them ultimately being on the same underlying commodity.
Nevertheless, how would you compute IV(U,Z) having only information on the Z future? What models would you suggest/any readings?
An "early expiry" volatility adjustment in essence is what I am looking for, with the aim of constructing the full vol term structure from today to expiry in order to price a strip of options.
Thanks!

We can use the fact that variance scales linearly with time under the assumption of log-normal returns
$$\text{Var} = \sigma^2 \cdot T$$
To estimate intermediate volatility, we have to use the total variance and interpolate it.
We do this by taking a time-weighted average of the known variances:
$$\sigma_{\text{interpolated}}^2 = \frac{T_{U}}{T_{Z}} \sigma_{Z}^2 + \left(1 - \frac{T_{U}}{T_{Z}}\right) \sigma_{U}^2$$
With
$$\frac{T_{U}}{T_{Z}}: \text{Proportion of the time until } T_{U} \text{ relative to } T_{Z}.$$
$$\left(1 - \frac{T_{U}}{T_{Z}}\right): \text{Remaining proportion relative to } T_{Z}.$$
However, because it's an American option you theoretically should account for some early exercise premium adjustment

In commodities there’s often no easy relationship between different deliveries (eg for gas or electricity, the fact that you can’t easily store them means that the September and the December contract can be very different things!)
